# SB Admin 2 Bootstrap theme compatibility problems with font awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, yii2-advanced-app

When I install `yii` advanced application and `bootstrap` theme *SB Admin 2* and after I map the view to the new theme, I get thrown this error :

> Declaration of p2made\helpers\base\FontAwesome::s() should be
>   compatible with rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\FontAwesome::s($options =
>   Array).

Can any one help me and tell me the way to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is just to copy the function s() of **rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\FontAwesome.php** and past it in **p2made\helpers\base\FontAwesome.php**.
Make sure to delete the s() function before past the new one.

the problem that i have now is that after an composer update alle these changes will be gone, a,d the theme will throw the same exception.